# jMenu bar in Java Swing not enabling issue

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenubar

I have a jMenu bar and it is enabled by default. On selecting first item, I am disabling the jMenu

[image]

Here is code on first menu item. Basically `ViewCustomerAccountsDetails` is a jInterframe :-

```
       ViewCustomerAccountsDetails vca = new ViewCustomerAccountsDetails();
        this.jDesktopPane1.add(vca);
        vca.show();
        jMenu1.setEnabled(false);
```

Now, in class `ViewCustomerAccountsDetails`, I have a Button and on its click, i am hiding this JInternal frame and
trying to enable the jMenu bar :-

```
    CustomerMainScreenLogin cmsl = new CustomerMainScreenLogin();
    cmsl.jMenu1.setEnabled(true); //jMenu is public
    this.dispose();
```

But it is not working. It is still disabled.

Comment: Are you getting any error? and is your `jMenu1` public static?

Comment: @Prasad - as i have mentioned above , it is public but not static

Comment: Why dont you use JPanel instead of JInternalFrame?

Comment: I am talking about the Menu item not the container

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
CustomerMainScreenLogin cmsl = new CustomerMainScreenLogin(); // A new instance? Why?
cmsl.jMenu1.setEnabled(true); //Here jMenu1 references the new instance menu 1, not the current one's.
this.dispose();
```

Why do you create a new instance of `CustomerMainScreenLogin` class? Most likely `jMenu1` is enabled but in a new non visible `CustomerMainScreenLogin` object. To make it visible just call `cms1.setVisible(true)` and you'll see that.

So you need to reference the current instance of `CustomerMainScreenLogin` class instead of creating a new one. For instance by making `jMenu1` static and calling `jMenu1.setEnabled(true)` in this way:

```
CustomerMainScreenLogin.jMenu1.setEnabled(true);
this.dispose();
```

Comment: You are right. Better not to set them to static. In my case some global static variables don't respond to my `setEnabled(true)` call while via getters, other private member do. Just use private members and call getter/setter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure where, but an invokeLater is probably needed. This does the heavy work a bit later, and allows the event queue thread to handle all events, like the button click fast and keep responsive and reactive - as with menus being enabled.

```
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            jMenu1.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    vca.show();

    cmsl.jMenu1.setEnabled(true);
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            dispose();
        }
    }
```